# Discord.js autorole from username

Tags: discord.js

I want to make my bot autorole if username of anyone member contains a specific tag and the code i made isn't working, bot starts fine but didn't assign role if user have tag in username than also so i thought to use stackoverflow to get some help

Here is the code:

```
client.on("userUpdate", async (oldUser, newUser) => {
  if (oldUser.username !== newUser.username) {
    let tag = "⚡"; 
    let server_id = "793143091350470708";  
    let role = "888436049620119562";
    if (newUser.username.includes(tag) && !client.guilds.get(server_id).members.get(newUser.id).roles.has(role)) {
      client.guilds.get(server_id).members.get(newUser.id).addRole(role)
    } if (!newUser.username.includes(tag) && client.guilds.get(server_id).members.get(newUser.id).roles.has(role)) {
      client.guilds.get(server_id).members.get(newUser.id).removeRole(role)  
    }

  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would require to define `USER_UPDATE`, `GUILD_MEMBER_UPDATE`, and
`PRESENCE_UPDATE` intents if you are on discord.js version 13 and further enable the members and presence intent too, they can be located in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developer) further I would like to suggest using the [`Client#guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) listener instead since your code has nothing to do with presence you would not need the "extra" intents.

## Additional Information

Directed by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69475166/discord-js-autorole-from-username/69476599?noredirect=1#comment122811181_69476599) It has come to my notice that you are using version 12 of discord.js so you would want to make adequate changes to your code for that ( your code as it currently is, is clearly written for discord.js v11) the following changes would be made in your code:

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", async (oldUser, newUser) => {
  if (oldUser.username !== newUser.username) {
    let tag = "⚡"; 
    let server_id = "793143091350470708";  
    let role = "888436049620119562";
    if (newUser.username.includes(tag) && !client.guilds.cache.get(server_id).members.cache.get(newUser.id).roles.has(role)) {
      client.guilds.cache.get(server_id).members.cache.get(newUser.id).roles.add(role)
    } if (!newUser.username.includes(tag) && client.guilds.cache.get(server_id).members.cache.get(newUser.id).roles.has(role)) {
      client.guilds.cache.get(server_id).members.cache.get(newUser.id).roles.remove(role)  
    }

  }
})
```

Comment: i am on v12 discord.js and have enabled all intents

Comment: @Zero you have a typo in your snippet, there is a double dot in the `if` condition.

Comment: thanks you all this website stack overflow is actually helpful